# Android Menu Option always become list menu not grid menu

Tags: android, menu

hi i wanna make grid option menu instead of list option menu
but no mather i try (xml or programmatically) i always get list option menu like this

[image]

i wanna create grid menu something like this

[image]

this is code i use

**XML**

```
<item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Option1"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Option2"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Option3"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="Option4"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item5" android:title="Option5"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item6" android:title="Option6"></item>
```

**Programatically**

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(1, 1, 0, "Option1");
    menu.add(1, 2, 1, "Option2");
    menu.add(1, 3, 2, "Option3");
    menu.add(1, 4, 3, "Option4");
    menu.add(1, 5, 4, "Option5");

    menu.add(2, 6, 0, "Option6");
    menu.add(2, 7, 1, "Option7");
    menu.add(2, 8, 2, "Option8");
    menu.add(2, 9, 3, "Option9");
    menu.add(2, 10, 4, "Option10");

 return true;
```

}

---

**Update @Krupa Patel**
hm, i used android 2.3.3 and you're right i used holo theme
i don't mind to change theme, but i can't find

```
@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar
```

instead i found

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > in AandroidmMnifest.xml (root firectory)
```

is it right? i try to change it to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar" >
```

but it's give error message

---

**Update**

i try to create new project and change theme (wizardly)
i see there is available 4 option for theme when i create new project
"none" - "Holo Dark" - "Holo Light" - "Holo Light with Dark Action Bar"
i choice "none" and when i run my new project menu..it's still become list menu not as i expect....any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Displaying option menu as grid-style in Android 4.0.3. is not working, because you may used @android:style/Theme.Holo for your application. Menu of Theme.Holo was set for displaying in list-style.

The solutions are:

1. Try to use another theme such as

`@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar`

**instead of @android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar**

1. Or if you want to use Theme.Holo only, then try to create a style for menu in values/style.xml. References: see styles in Android Framework.

Hope this will help!